# Modify author archive query to combine two queries

Tags: pre-get-posts

I'm working on a site that allows multiple authors on posts by using an "additional authors" Posts to Posts connection type.  Posts still have a standard author, but they can optionally have additional authors.

I'd like to modify the author archive query to include *all* posts by the author, including those where they are an "additional" author.  This isn't as simple as just adding parameters to the main author query, so in `pre_get_posts` I'm combining two queries by getting the matching post IDs from both, then running a `post__in` query.

Thats works, but I can't figure out how to pass the results of that query to the author template.  Changing the `author` query var means that the site doesn't show the author archive template.

tl;dr - can you use `pre_get_posts` to fully customize the author archive query, and include posts that are *not* actually authored by that user?

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I've found to override the main author archive query in a way that will include posts that aren't created by the specified user is by using the `posts_where` filter.

For example:

```
        $post_ids = function_that_gets_desired_post_ids();

        add_filter('posts_where', function($where) use ($post_ids){

            $post_ids = array_map(function($id){
                return (int) $id;
            }, $post_ids);

            $in = implode(',', $post_ids);
            $where .= " OR (ID IN ($in) AND post_type = 'post')";
            return $where;

        });
```

Using something like this doesn't make me feel good, but it does work.